# C#, call method - only if not currently called

Tags: c#, concurrency

I've a method which looks like this:

```
void Foo ()
{
    bool flag;
    do
    {
        flag = false;

        var check = CheckSomething();
        if(check)
        {
            DoSomething();
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    while(flag);
}
```

Currently I'm calling the method using the following code snippet (which is executed in many worker threads):

```
Bar(); // this method may affect the outcome of CheckSomething()
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Foo());
```

- It is important to me that the loop body is always run *soon* after Bar() has been called, **but**
- `CheckSomething()` is expensive and therefore I do not want `Foo()` to be called more often than required

Is there a guaranteed-safe way to call `Foo()` if and only if it is not already executed and going to call `CheckSomething()` before exiting?

Comment: Based on the code in `Foo` it's always going to call `CheckSomething()` before exiting (unless of course you mean something much more complex) so it appears the constraint is **if it's not already executed.** Is that right?

Comment: Not exactly. It could be that `Bar()` is called after `CheckSomething()` already return `false`, however, still due the execution of `Foo()`.

Comment: Okay, so I can't really test this per say, but it seems to me that in the `Foo` method - right before the `if` - you'd want to *dequeue* an item from the thread pool.

Comment: Further, you'd need to lock a shared object when both queueing and dequeueing.

Comment: So I think the reasons you're having problems here is because of problems within the implementation of `CheckSomething`.  Based on your comments it sounds like it's relying on shared memory between threads and as such you never really know what it'll do when you call it.  You should avoid putting yourself in that position to begin with.

Comment: @Servy: Thank you, but I'm not in the position to change the "shared memory situation".

Comment: @neoistheone: I don't get exactly what you mean. Do I need an additional queue or are you talking about the ThreadPool queue?

Comment: @D.R., I was talking about dequeueing an item from the thread pool. The one you're queueing calls into.

Comment: The thread pool is the .NET default thread pool. Are you sure you can dequeue items from there? Why would I want to dequeue them before the *if* and not before the call to `CheckSomething()`? Why would I want to dequeue only one item?

Comment: @D.R. It's hard to tell, as you haven't really given enough details about what these things are doing, but it looks like what you want to do isn't going to be *possible* in a multithreaded context without at least some changes to these methods.  It seems like `CheckSomething` really needs to accept a parameter of some result returned from `Bar` so that you can ensure it's checking the right thing, and without that, you'll never get it working.

Comment: @D.R., I believe I stated after the if because it would guarantee that `CheckSomething` had been called - and you might be right about dropping the entire queue.

Comment: @QtX: Thank you for downvoting my question just because your answer was plain wrong! That's the SO spirit!

Comment: @neoistheone: I'm going to play with that...still I'm open for any proven solution :-)

Comment: @Servy: I think that's worth a shot...I guess I'll try to add some kind of versioning to the shared memory...maybe that helps!

Comment: @D.R. If you can't actually modify the code at all to ensure a proper API for your objects that are accessed from multiple threads I would strongly encourage you to just not call them from multiple threads.  As I said, ensuring that this will actually work properly would most likely require adding locks such that all of the code is run synchronously, in which case there's no reason to create multiple threads to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Servy's comments I've now managed to solve the problem by versioning my shared memory:

- Each call to `Bar` increases the version of the underlying shared memory
- `Bar` returns the new current version which I pass on to `Foo`
- `Foo` passes the current version to a `CheckSomething`-wrapper
- `CheckSomething`-wrapper returns false immediately if the given version is smaller than the shared memory's current version -> `Foo` exits

The only problem has been that too many calls to `Bar` in a short time range are starving the `Foo` method, which is why I run it anyways if the version difference is more than a constant value (e.g. 50).

Thanks once more for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent `Foo` from running if it's already being executed. Seems like you can use a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) for that.

```
private object fooLock = new object();

void Foo ()
{
    // Try to acquire the lock
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(fooLock))
    {
        // Some other thread is already in this method.
        return;
    }

    bool flag;
    do
    {
        flag = false;

        var check = CheckSomething();
        if(check)
        {
            DoSomething();
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    while(flag);

    // release the lock
    Monitor.Exit(fooLock);
}
```

(For those wondering why I didn't put the `Monitor.Exit` in a `finally` clause, see Eric Lippert's [Locks and exceptions do not mix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx).)

That won't prevent `Foo` from being called, but it will prevent multiple threads from being in the loop, so `CheckSomething` can't be called concurrently from within `Foo`.

Your requirements are a bit vague, so it's possible this won't do exactly what you want. There's some ambiguity about what you want to happen if one thread has already called `CheckSomething` and got `false` back, but hasn't yet exited, and another thread enters the method. Handling that race condition would be a bit trickier.

Comment: This would still call `CheckSomething()` ten times if `Bar()` is called ten times. Thank you for your detailed answer anyways!

Comment: @D.R. You asked: *"Is there a guaranteed-safe way to call Foo() if and only if it is not already executed and going to call CheckSomething() before exiting?"* This prevents `CheckSomething` from being called concurrently, which is what your question says you want. If you want some different behavior, then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @D.R. Do note that the use of `TryEnter` here doesn't block the calling thread, but rather causes it to exit `Foo` if some other thread already has the lock. It's not the same thing as `lock` or `Monitor.Enter`.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that, sorry. Still, there seems to be a catch: what happens if one thread has already exited the loop but has not yet exited the monitor. The second thread enters Foo and returns, however, CheckSomething may have returned true.